# How can I export a file to FBX or gITF format with MeshSequenceCache animation from Marvelous Designer?

Tags: animation, modifiers, export, cache, webgl

[image]

I created a cloth simulation animation using Marvelous designer, then I imported this file as Alembic format into Blender. Everything works great in Blender I can view the animation no problem. Now, I want to export this as a FBX or gITF 2.0 file so I can use three.js to view the animation in the web. However, this does not work. For some reason the animation is gone. I can confirm this when I import the file back into Blender, the MeshSequenceCache modifer is gone. Does anyone know how I can convert MeshSequenceCache into keyframes, so I can then export this as a gITF file?

Comment: Is it gone or simply inactive? I have no experience with this, but can imagine it's like an animated gif that contains all the frames but is not triggered to play its animation.

Comment: I would try exporting the animation to MDD, then re-import the MDD file into Blender, which converts the whole thing to a shape key sequence. Blender can export shape key sequences to glTF.  This does require that mesh topology and vertex count do not change over the course of the animation, I think.